# redirect using htacess for a path to another path retaining old path's file name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect a URL: `www.example.com/folder1/folder2/about.php`

To another URL given at: `www.example.com/folderA/about.php`

Is that possible using .htacess? I am using Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes this is possible. Try this rule before Wordpress rules

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Your redirect rules

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/folder1\/folder2\/([^\/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/folderA/%1 [R=301,NC,L]

# Your redirect rules

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```